# How javascript uses features of web browser which not included in javascript

Tags: javascript

My question is setTimeout function and other web ApIs written in another programming language ? how javascript uses the other programming language features because other programming language syntax is different. Is there any translator between them which converts the code of another language in javascript ?.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're asking. Syntax is not the same thing as the standard library, and even that differs between JavaScript runtimes (browsers, Node.js, Rhino, ...)

Comment: `setTimeout` is not  a part of JavaScript. That's implemented by browser's interpreters, say v8 Engine. JavaScript supports only sequential code execution. You might like to read `event-loop` in JS as well.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi - V8 doesn't implement `setTimeout`, the host does. (V8 *does* have a `setTimeout` placeholder -- you can see this if you run V8 without any host -- but it doesn't actually do a timer, it just calls the function immediately.)

Comment: Runtimes like web browsers or NodeJS extend javascript with apis and functions like setTimeout, but that not are included in ecmascript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for clarifying in details :) (y)

Comment: @RahulDwivedi - Actually, I misspoke a bit above. I don't think V8 itself has the `setTimeout` placeholder, I think it's provided by the thin wrapper executable that comes with it for testing (used to be called D8, but they seem to be moving away from that). (It can be fun to play with V8 directly -- https://mths.be/jsvu.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder cool. So where exactly `setTimeout` /`promises` implementations reside? At `V8` level or on the browser(host) itself somewhere and it just passes them to the the engine?

Comment: @RahulDwivedi - Timers are implemented by the host, because they're host-specific features. Promises are part of JavaScript, so they're implemented by the JavaScript engine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder cool. I used to misinterpret `promises` as being implemented on browsers because JavaScript, as we know, supports synchronous execution only after all.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi - Indeed, the ES2015 spec where promises were added was the first edition of the specification to define any asynchronous behavior. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *language* translation involved, no, although there's definitely a boundary between the environments.

When a browser uses a JavaScript engine, the browser provides some things to the engine in order for the engine to do its work. One of those things is the global object, which has methods and properties on it that provide host-specific features (like the DOM, `setTimeout`, etc.). The browser also provides functions to the JavaScript engine that aren't exposed to JavaScript code, for doing things like [resolving modules](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule).

Think of the JavaScript engine as a library embedded in the browser application. The browser code calls into the library to do things like create a new environment for a window/tab, and provides functions to the library that it calls to do things like schedule timer callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Those functions exposed from the browser.

Basically it goes like

- lex the js
- do proper actions (wait for the timeout for instance)
- push the callback back to js stack (possibly with extra data from the result of the native function)

about your second question whether there are any "transpilers" transpiling oter languages to js:

There are plenty of transpilers the simplest example is `tsc` which transpiles typescript to javascript

Also you didnt ask but I feel like you want to learn how things work so I will add a bonus.

WebAssembly is a binary format for the browser and it is a compiler target for many languages which means without bothering to transpile things to js you can simply comile your native program to webassembly and run native code in your browser